# call is getting disconnected in dialogflow cx?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am using Dialogflow cx. In the dialogflowcx integrations, I'm using phone gateway. Call is getting connected but it is getting disconnected after 3 questions. What could be the reason ??

Also how to disconnect the call in dialogflow cx?

Approximate answer is expected

Comment: The Dialogflow CX phone gateway has some limitations.You can follow this [article](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/phone-gateway#limits) regarding the same. Let me know whether this is helpful or not.

Comment: How to disconnect the call in dialogflow cx

Comment: According to this [gcp documention](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/phone-gateway#call_the_telephone_number) when the agent  reaches the end session state, the call will end.

Answer (score 0):

1. Network issues: If the Dialogflow CX or phone gateway network is experiencing issues, the call may drop.
2. [Timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpuXP.png): There may be a timeout setting in your Dialogflow CX agent that is configured to disconnect the call after a certain period of time.

3. [Enable Enable auto speech adaptation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdb97.png):
   Use agent information (e.g. intents, entities) to automatically improve speech recognition quality.
4. [there is no 4.]